# Is that possible to change Block parameters and values in a standalone Simulink Model with a C# application?

Tags: c#, matlab, simulink

I have a classic PID controller simulink model. I do not want to configure my simulink model for every different application. I just want to do it by entering parameters from my `C# window forms` application.

Is that possible? Of course, I do not demand a detailed solution. Just "Yes, with basicly this method" or "No, not yet". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way to configure your Simulink model is normally from MATLAB using the [`set_param`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/set_param.html) command. If you can get your C# application to talk to MATLAB and issue various `set_param` commands based on the user inputs, then it should be doable. However, I don't know enough about C# to know whether it's possible to do so or not.

Comment: Just realised you said "standalone" Simulink model, so I assume you must use some form of code generation. Not sure if my method would work with code generated from a model. You probably need to define the parameters of interest as tunable parameters, but how you would then go about changing them from the C# application is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, when i comes to standalone code, it gets complicated for me too. Actually when I say standalone I reffer to a simulink model which is embedded in a microcontroller.

Comment: If the code generated from the model is embedded in a microcontroller, then you need to define the parameters of interest as tunable parameters (check the doc for Simulink/Embedded Coder), and then find a mechanism to pass the values to the code running on the microcontroller from the C# application. Arguably, this is a C/C++/C# question, not really a Simnulink question.

Comment: You are complately right. But I just do not know how to define those parameter as "tunable".

Comment: Have a look at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/gui/optimization-pane-signals-and-parameters.html. You need to tick "Inline parameters" and then click on "Configure..." to select which ones are tunable. As I said, this should be detailed in the Simulink Coder/Embedded Coder documentation.